# How to access CURL command in Java

Tags: java, url, curl

I am trying to access the link through CURL in Java.

Here is my CURL Command:

```
curl -X POST --insecure --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "{\"searchText\":\"10200597\",\"qf\":\"applId\"}" “https://ped.uspto.gov/api/queries
```

I tried by using `HttpURLConnection`, but it didn't worked for me. Is there any best way to access command?

Comment: Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: You need to provide what you have tried with HttpURLConnection. Just because it did not worked for you does not mean it is not the answer

Answer (score 0):

By using `ProcessBuilder` we can solve this:

Here is sample code:

```
String[] cmd = {"curl", "-X", "POST", "--insecure", "--header", "Content-Type: application/json", "--header", "Accept: application/json", "-d", "{\"searchText\":\"10200597\",\"qf\":\"applId\"}", "https://ped.uspto.gov/api/queries"};
        ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder(cmd); 
        Process p;
        try
        {
            p = process.start();
             BufferedReader reader =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        builder.append(line);
                        builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                }
                String result = builder.toString();
                System.out.print(result);

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {   System.out.print("error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```